# Find index of array of objects inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 array of objects with as shown below.
I want to find the index by searching the child array 'sub' in parent array 'array1' keeping id as the key.

I want to search sub array in array1 and find the index of values like [0,1,2,3].

Hence my expected output should be [0,1,2,3].

```
//parent array    
 array1 = [
    { "id": "1111", "name": "a1"},
    { "id": "2222", "name": "a2" },
    { "id": "3333", "name": "a3" },
    { "id": "4444", "name": "a4" },
    {"id": "5555", "name": "a5" },
];


//child array
 sub = [
    { "id": "1111"},
    { "id": "2222" }        
];
```

I'm struggling with find the child array on the parent array
as it includes the array of objects with key values.

Comment: why do you want all indices from `array1`? why do you have `sub` array. in which relation are both arrays? please add the wanted real result.

Comment: Is it always `{"id": some_number}` elements of `sub`? What should happen if there's no such element in `array1`?

Comment: @NinaScholz  Sub array is generating on run time basically.
If sub array contains in array1, then we have to add all the indices of sub array values from array1.

If i remove any value from sub array, then the respective index should also be removed.

Please help me out on this addition/removal part.

Comment: @raina77ow  Yes it'll always be in this pattern only & array1 will always have the values generated from the system. It can never be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for all `id` of `sub` and then filter the indices for seen `id` of `array1`.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ id: "1111", name: "a1" }, { id: "2222", name: "a2" }, { id: "3333", name: "a3" }, { id: "4444", name: "a4" }, { id: "5555", name: "a5" }],
    sub = [{ id: "1111" }, { id: "2222" }],
    subIds = new Set(sub.map(({ id }) => id)),
    result = [...array1.keys()].filter(i => subIds.has(array1[i].id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you @Nina.
It is working fine. But i have one more requirement on this like

If i remove {id: "1111"} from sub, then the output should be output - [1] only.
But currently it is showing as [0,1].

How to incorporate the logic of removal of index also, if element removes from sub array ? 
Please help me out.

Comment: it should work for this, too.

Comment: It's working fine now.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two array in for loop like below.

```
const array1 = [
      { id: "1111", name: "a1" },
      { id: "2222", name: "a2" },
      { id: "3333", name: "a3" },
      { id: "4444", name: "a4" },
      { id: "5555", name: "a5" },
    ];
    
    //child array
    const sub = [{ id: "1111" }, { id: "2222" }];
    
    const indexes = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= sub.length - 1; i++) {
        const subID = sub[i].id;
      for (let j = 0; j <= array1.length - 1; j++) {
          const parentID = array1[j].id;
    
          if(parentID === subID){
              indexes.push(j)
          }
      }
    }
```